# Jquery Accordion open based upon .class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion

I have the following JQuery code to operate my accordion menu.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        function close_accordion_section() {
            $('.accordion .accordion-section-title').removeClass('active');
            $('.accordion .accordion-section-content').slideUp(300).removeClass('open');
        }
        $('.accordion-section-title').click(function(e) {
            // Grab current anchor value
            var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');

            if($(e.target).is('.active')) {
                close_accordion_section();
            }else {
                close_accordion_section();

                // Add active class to section title
                $(this).addClass('active');
                // Open up the hidden content panel
                $('.accordion ' + currentAttrValue).slideDown(300).addClass('open'); 
            }

            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
    </script>
```

How do I modify the code to detect the 'current' class and open the corresponding panel from the following html script.

```
<div class="main" style="width:300px">
    <div class="accordion">
        <div class="accordion-section">
           <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-1">accordion-1</a>
           <div id="accordion-1" class="accordion-section-content" >
              <ul class="nav menuside">
                  <li><a href="#">Here</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Here</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Here</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Here</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Here</a></li>
              </ul>
           </div>
        </div>
    <div class="accordion-section">
        <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-2">accordion-2</a>
        <div id="accordion-2" class="accordion-section-content">
            <ul class="nav menuside">
                <li><a href="#">Here</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Here</a></li>
                <li class="current"><a href="#">Here</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Here</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Here</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--end .accordion-section-content-->
    </div><!--end .accordion-section-->
  </div>
</div>
```

How to current class in for open accordion panel.

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly? I found your code is working. 
`currentAttrValue` is an id, you don't need to prepend `.accordion`.
You can use `e.target` to get the DOM node, then wrap it with jQuery, and use `.attr("class")` to get the classes. If you want to keep track of something precise, you can use data-tags ; add `data-myattr='someValue'` to your HTML markup, then access it with `$(e.target).data("myattr")`.
Make a fiddle maybe.